# Getting Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue empty query

Tags: java, sql

When I execute this code, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue empty query
```

What is wrong with my code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    // for keyboard input
    System.out.println("Enter Employee id: ");
    int empid = Integer.parseInt(d.readLine());

    System.out.println("Enter Employee name: ");
    String empname = d.readLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Employee Salary: ");
    double empsalary = Double.parseDouble(d.readLine());

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); // Loading MYSQL Driver
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee", "root", "admin");
    PreparedStatement pst = con
            .prepareStatement("insert into employee values(?,?,?)");
    pst.setInt(1, empid);
    pst.setString(2, empname);
    pst.setDouble(3, empsalary);
    int rowcount = pst.executeUpdate("");
    System.out.println(rowcount + "row has been insereted");

}
```

Comment: Error massage seems to be related to `pst.executeUpdate("");`. Have you tried with `pst.executeUpdate();`?

Comment: WOrked thanks. But why should'nt i put quotes ?

Comment: You probably should read documentations of [executeUpdate(String sql)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-) and [executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--) and you will notice that `String sql` is parameter representing an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE which should be executed. In your case this statement is empty and because of that you see your SQLException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are calling `executeUpdate(String)` from the `Statement` interface, not the `executeUpdate()` from `PreparedStatement`.

Remove the two quotes and it should work